# Change font into MS Gothic

Tags: fonts

just wanted to ask how can I change the font of Section 1 , 2 and english paragraph into MS Gothic FONT? Japanese and English version

For the japanese font: ＭＳ ゴシック

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
\section{MS Gothic これは最初のセクションである}
日本語で \LaTeX の組版を実証するための導入部分。

フォントはまた、数学的な形態および他の環境で使用することができる
\end{CJK*}

\bigskip

\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont Outside the environment Latin characters may be used.

\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{goth}
\section{MS Gothic これは最初のセクションである}
日本語で \LaTeX の組版を実証するための導入部分。

フォントはまた、数学的な形態および他の環境で使用することができる
\end{CJK*}

\end{document}
```

This is the MS Gothic font

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can run `pdffonts test.pdf` to see the font information. These code below in run on `XeLaTeX`. Maybe you have to install the Helvetica font on your computer. I test it on TeX Live 2022 and Windows 10.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{MS Gothic}[BoldFont={MS Gothic},BoldFeatures={FakeBold=2}]
% \setCJKmainfont{MS Gothic}[BoldFont={MS Gothic}]
\setmainfont{Helvetica}

\begin{document}

\section{MS Gothic これは最初のセクションである}
日本語で \LaTeX の組版を実証するための導入部分。

フォントはまた、数学的な形態および他の環境で使用することができる

Outside the environment Latin characters may be used.

\section{MS Gothic これは最初のセクションである}
日本語で \LaTeX の組版を実証するための導入部分。

フォントはまた、数学的な形態および他の環境で使用することができる

\end{document}
```

### Fakebold of MS Gothic

[image]

### Non-Fakebold of MS Gothic

[image]